# Separar columna según Regex

Tags: python, regex

tengo una columna donde viene texto asociado a un porcentaje. Dentro de una columna, pueden aparecer hasta 3 veces estos textos.

Ejemplo:

`datos = {'Conducta':['HOLA QUIERO PROBAR ALGO 65%, TENGO HAMBRE 55%, EL OTRO DIA FUI A COMPRAR 23%']}`

Cuando extraigo usando regex, solamente puedo separar el primer texto con el primer porcentaje, pero no sé como replicar esto para poder hacerlo en los otros dos restantes.

`df['Conducta'].str.extract('([A-Za-z\s]+)\s?(\d+[.0-9]+%)?\s?\(?(.*(?=\)))?')`

```
0   1   2
0   HOLA QUIERO PROBAR ALGO 65% NaN
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Algo así es a lo que aspiro llegar...

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar `extractall()` en lugar del extract, pero te va a echar varias filas:

```
df['Conducta'].str.extractall('([A-Za-z\s]+)\s?(\d+[.0-9]+%)?\s?\(?(.*(?=\)))?')
```

Te devuelve

```
                                   0    1    2
  match
0 0         HOLA QUIERO PROBAR ALGO   65%  NaN
  1                    TENGO HAMBRE   55%  NaN
  2       EL OTRO DIA FUI A COMPRAR   23%  NaN
```

Simplemente necesitas añadirle `unstack()`

```
df['Conducta'].str.extractall('([A-Za-z\s]+)\s?(\d+[.0-9]+%)?\s?\(?(.*(?=\)))?').unstack()
```

Y devuelve

```
                              0                                                 1              2
match                         0               1                            2    0    1    2    0    1    2
0      HOLA QUIERO PROBAR ALGO    TENGO HAMBRE    EL OTRO DIA FUI A COMPRAR   65%  55%  23%  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Que, bueno, serían las columnas en desorden (separadas por el grupo de captura del regex)

Comment: Muchas gracias Danny!!, Eso era lo que necesitaba